# What is the curve's name for the "reciprocal" equation of a circle?

Tags: functions, circles

The equation of a unit circle is  $$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$$
When the origin $$(a, b)=(0,0)$$ the equation becomes $$y=(1-x^2)^{1/2}$$
Naturally when this equation is plotted on graph paper we get a circle centred at the intersection of both axes.
When the right hand side of the equation is plotted as the reciprocal of the previous relation it becomes $$y=1/(1-x^2)^{1/2}$$ But what is the mathematical name given for this curve?

(This curve is synonymous with the reciprocal of the Lorentz factor in special relativity, otherwise known as the time dilation factor)

Answer (score 0):

There is no special name (as far as I know) for the curve $$y=1/(1-x^2)^{1/2}$$

It looks like [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bw12dqya3p).